# Django Database error

Tags: python, django

I am trying to insert data into the database.Table is created but during inserting data it is giving error got an unexpected   keyword of column name (coursecode).But in the database column name is coursecode.
code for model.py 
    from django.db import models

```
# Create your models here.
class course(models.Model):
   coursecode=models.CharField(max_length=10)
   coursename=models.CharField(max_length=10)
   startdate=models.CharField(max_length=10)
   enddate=models.CharField(max_length=10)
   image=models.CharField(max_length=10)
   credits=models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

and the views.py is

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.core.files.base import File
from course.models import course
from django.db.models import Q
from django.core.context_processors import csrf
# Create your views here.
def course(request):
  if(request.method == 'POST'):
    course_id1 = request.POST.get('coursecode', '')
    course_name1 = request.POST.get('coursename', '')
    credits1 = request.POST.get('creditwa', '')
    end_date1=request.POST.get('enddate', '')
    start_date1=request.POST.get('startdate', '')
    image1=request.FILES.get('image','')
    image2=request.FILES.get('image').name
    course_data=course(coursecode=course_id1,coursename=course_name1,startdate=start_date1,enddate=end_date1,image=image2,creditwa=credits1
    )
    course_data.save()

return render(request,'course.html',{'form':''})



traceback error
course() got an unexpected keyword argument 'coursecode'
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    
Django Version: 1.6.1
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
course() got an unexpected keyword argument 'coursecode'
Exception Location: /home/vc/portal/course/views.py in course, line 23
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.6
Python Path:    
['/home/vc/portal',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools-7.0-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django_socketio-0.3.9-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sphinx_me-0.3-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gevent_socketio-0.2.1-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gevent_websocket-0.9.3-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0',
 '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client']
Server time:    Tue, 11 Nov 2014 14:09:09 +0000
```

Comment: You should show the actual error and traceback. You do not have any code mentioning "courseid" in the code you have posted. (And not related, but you should almost certainly be using a Django form here.)

Comment: Your class is named `course`, and your view is also `course`. Which course are you calling in the second last line of your view ?